# discord.py trivia command error, when answer trivia correctly, it says I don't have an account to give me currency, yet I am registered

Tags: python, discord.py

I am using discord.py to make a multipurpose bot. It has a currency in it called rb. The way I do the currency is I have a .json file called amounts, and all the commands that give you currency work, apart from trivia.

Here is the code for the trivia command:

```
@bot.command(name='trivia', help='Gives you a random trivia question, if you answer right, you get rb!')
@commands.cooldown(1, 60, commands.BucketType.user)
async def trivia(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Trivia time! When was mario created? 1996, 1981')
# this sends the question

    def check(m):
        return m.author.id == ctx.author.id
# this checks if the user who initiated the cmd is the one who talks

    time3 = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
# this is waiting for a message to be sent
    if time3.content == '1996':
        if ctx.message.author.id in amounts:
           await ctx.send('Correct! You earned 50rb!')
           amounts[ctx.message.author.id] += 50
        else:
            await ctx.send("Correct! You would've just got some rb, but you aren't registered! Type r!register to start!")

    elif time3.content == '1981':
        await ctx.send('F you got it incorrect.')
    else:
        await ctx.send('thats not a valid answer come on man')
```

The bot just says: 
'Correct! You would've just got some rb, but you aren't registered! Type r!register to start!'

If anyone could help me fix this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Please update your code to include what `amounts` is and how registration works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it wasn't working is because I wasn't getting `str(ctx.message.author.id)` which is the actual id. Since I was trying to get an int, but in the .json file ids are stored as strings, then (obviously) it wasn't showing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it tells you this, because **ctx.message.author.id** is NOT in **amounts**, since that's what you've set it up to say in that scenario. Make sure you're "registered" in your json file, and that you don't forget to dump the new values of **amounts** into it after you've changed them.
Also, you should pull the data out of the json file every time the command is used, to get the fresh current values.

Comment: ctx.message.author.id is in amounts, since when I check in the amounts.json file, I can find where it is.

Comment: Again, make sure to pull the data out every time the command is used, to have the newest values. You're currently not doing that. Thus you're probably comparing old values.